# Rbenv for production with passenger

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install rbenv on my Debian 6 system for production. What is the best way to do this? I tried some tuts from the github wiki page (https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Using-rbenv-in-production and https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/shared-install-of-rbenv), but I'm wondering what is the best practise.

Is it better to install it with a deploy user or system wide? With a deploy user, it seems that the rubies aren't available for all users, even if I install it with `rbenv global 1.9.3-p125` and the `gem` commando isn't available too. This must be something with my paths, cause I only included the

```
if [[ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]]; then
  export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

in the `.bashrc` file of my deploy user. Does passenger/apache know where my rubies are? Because apache is running with the `www-data` user.

With system wide install (see shared installation link above) I ran in some strange error, that the rbenv command wasn't found and could not be compiled.

So, what should I do? I want to use it for my production server so that I can easily switch between rubies in the future.

Comment: It's important to note that can't use different Ruby installations with just Passenger's Apache module, as it must be compiled against the Ruby being used, and the configuration must point to that install.

Comment: I know that this isn't possible. But in the future, if I want to use a different ruby version, I think it's easier with rbenv to switch, as it would be with a normal system installation Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I personally would go the deploy user route and use the rbenv-sudo plugin for edge cases like passenger-install, chef or things like that.  I think the majority of people don't use rbenv or rvm for production which is why a [lot of people are stuck on 1.8](http://blog.newrelic.com/2011/09/28/state-of-the-stack-a-ruby-on-rails-benchmarking-report-sept-2011/).  It's a shame because as you said, it'd be nice to easily switch Ruby versions.  That being said, production shouldn't switch Ruby that often right?  You can pretty easily manage ruby versions yourself by using configure flags from Ruby source.  Just don't install into /usr/bin.

Sstephenson says that the shared install is experimental in that shared-install-of-rbenv link.  Rbenv global isn't going to do anything across user accounts.  It's global within a user account.

Outside of the deploy user, how many accounts do you need on production?

Answer (score 0):

you should specify the user(that passenger uses) has the access privilege to your rbenv.